# How to use Google Fonts with Ionic2 RC0 / RC1?

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my app.scss I put: `@import '../theme/variables';`

and in my variables.scss I put:

```
@import "ionic.globals";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300);
```

However fonts are not loading (I checked network traffic).

Any idea how to do this? Maybe even offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working Solution

Root Cause was that I used `.ttf` instead of binary `.woff` files.

#### theme/variables.scss

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
     src: url('../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.woff');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }

 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Oswald';
     src: url('../assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the offline method.

Move the fonts/ folder into the www/ folder, so it looks like this.

```
| scss/
  |-- basics/
    |--_fonts.scss
| www
  |-- fonts/
    |-- SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf
    |-- SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
```

Then, if you aren't minifying the resources, then the paths might be off by one level. This should fix the references.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Comment: In Ionic RC1 we have `assets/fonts` structure by design. RollUp would not copy your scss folder. How did you get google ttf fonts? I tried on their page they do not offer ttf only import statement code samples.

Comment: To download the fonts in ttf is really easy, go to https://fonts.google.com/ --> search for a font --> click on it --> click on 'Select this font' on the right hand side --> a popup window will open at the bottom --> expand o=it by clicking on it --> and click on the download button on the right hand side. The file structure can change but the concept remains the same.

Comment: OK I build it in, linked correctly but fonts are not rendereing... :(